# Зависимый Combobox и TextBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Есть 2 таблицы в БД:

```
ID | IDTYPE | NAME
1  | 1      | Наименование1

ID | NAME
1  | Тип1
```

И мне нужно сделать комбобокс и текстбокс. Когда в комбобоксе (1-я таблица) выбрано значение, в текстбокс должен отобразиться связанный по IDTYPE текст (2-я таблица). Комбобокс я сделал (все как обычно):

```
DisplayMemberPath="Name", SelectedValue="{Binding MyObject.GroupsID}" SelectedValuePath="ID"
```

MyObject.GroupsID - свойство модели, которое определяет значение комбобокса. A как получить IDTYPE, который бы можно было как-то использовать для вывода текста? MVVM.

Контекст - ViewModel с объектом MyObject, где есть свойство GroupsID и 2 List для таблиц (справочников), считанных из БД датаадаптером.

Comment: А причём тут ваша табличная структура? Покажите ваш `DataContext`.

Comment: А можно в виде (компилируемого) кода? Потому что воспринимать описания на слух не очень легко.

Comment: И да, почему у вас навигационные свойства отсутствуют — вы собираетесь джойны делать в VM, а не в базе?